How can I influence the treatment of Pydantic member names on generated Pydantic code from FastAPI?
When I specify the API and schema in FastAPI (OpenAPI) and let FastAPI generate the schema objects/classes, the member names are formatted snake case and get a alias name in camel case.
class ObjectIdentifier(BaseModel):
    """NOTE: This class is auto generated by OpenAPI Generator (https://openapi-generator.tech).

    Do not edit the class manually.

    ObjectIdentifier - a model defined in OpenAPI

        location: The location of this ObjectIdentifier.
        location_type: The location_type of this ObjectIdentifier.
    """

    location: str = Field(alias="location")
    location_type: str = Field(alias="locationType")

ObjectIdentifier.update_forward_refs()

But when I populate a Pydantic class using its constructor and a dictionary from a database result set, the dictionary needs to contain the keys (attribute names) written with camel case.
# code that works
object_info = ObjectInformation(
    objectId=ObjectIdentifier(location=location, locationType=location_type),
    objectInfo=object_info
)

# code that does not work
object_info = ObjectInformation(
    object_id=ObjectIdentifier(location=location, location_type=location_type),
    object_info=object_info
)

Can I make the generated Pydantic code use snake case attribte names?
I tried several approaches using alias_generators and the Config object within a custom base class, but I can not use these approaches, as the Pydantic code is generated and I did not yet figure out how to use them in my context.
Ideally, I can use a syntax like this:
object_info = ObjectInformation(**database_result)

with database_result like this:
database_result = dict(
    location: "some location",
    location_type: "some location type",
    object_info: "the important object info"
)

That dictionary is a result of a query to a SQL DB, I can not get camel case attribute names as the DB access converts every name to lowercase. Thus, I can only get snake case from the DB results.
Notice, that the Pydantic structure is nested, ObjectIdentifier inside ObjectInformation. I dont know if nesting should work like I tried it.
Python: 3.9
Pydantic: 3.10.15

Did you try to set model_config = ConfigDict(populate_by_name=True)?

@lord_haffi I read about this possibility, and allow_population_by_field_name for v1, but where in the chain of OpenAPI generation I can add this, I did not find out.

I think it's much easier to edit the auto-generated classes afterwards. Is that an option?

It's much better practice to separate your db models (should reflect the database structure) from schemas (should reflect input / output data format). If you would like to use pydantic for managing db models you could do something like this:
class BaseObject(BaseModel):
    # Your fields here


class ObjectSchema(BaseObject):
    # alias_generators / validators / or whatever else related to your API format


class ObjectDb(BaseObject):
    model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True)

But I would also recommend to consider using SQLAlchemy models / SQLModel for managing your db models.
